# Unable to acquire *precisely* timed videos in Matlab (using ImgAcq toolbox)

Tags: matlab, video-capture

When I try to record using the code below, the resulting videos have the correct number of frames and file lengths, but the recorded time is always slightly longer (as measured by filming a digital clock), a 60min recordings capture ~61min, and 5min recordings have extra 3-5sec (so time is skipped during recordings). Occasionally, the camera clearly show time skipping when it records for some time, then pauses for up to hour or so, and then resumes.

I am using a Basler GigE acA1300-60gm (http://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/area-scan-cameras/ace/aca1300-60gm) camera set to continuous triggering for several hours, and I need the acquired videos to have millisecond resolution. I am not sure why the recording times are so varied, am I using a wrong script for the job or does it have something to do with the hardware settings?

(Matlab R2014a on Windows 7)

```
vid = videoinput(adapter, deviceIDVar{1,1}, formatVar);  
vid.FramesPerTrigger = NoOfFramesPerFile;

src = getselectedsource(vid);   
src.FrameStartTriggerMode = 'On';
src.FrameStartTriggerSource = 'Line1';
src.FrameStartTriggerActivation = 'RisingEdge';
src.FrameStartTriggerMode = 'Off';
src.PacketSize = 8000;

triggerconfig(vid, 'hardware', 'DeviceSpecific', 'DeviceSpecific');
vid.TriggerRepeat = 0;
vid.LoggingMode = 'disk';

for i=1:FileLimit
      %file path and format settings  
      diskLogger = VideoWriter(filenameWithExt, 'MPEG-4');   
      diskLogger.FrameRate = 25;
      vid.DiskLogger = diskLogger;
      start(vid)
      wait(vid, Inf);
end

stop(vid)
delete(vid)
clear
```

---

Are here any better ways to acquire precisely timed videos (at 25FPS)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may depend on make and model of camera. Could you add that data?

Comment: Question updated with camera details (http://www.baslerweb.com/en/products/area-scan-cameras/ace/aca1300-60gm)

Comment: I am unable to find the documentation, but there should be some parameter specifying what happened when a trigger is raised before the previous image is processed. Maybe default configures this to skip the frame.

Comment: I will try to get my hands on the documentiation, but I am not sure if I will recognise wha I am looking for. In any event, if that was the case, would lowering the framerate result in more precise vids? That I can check easily